# mysql sum of rows considering two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone please tell me how to get the total sum of each tool no in Rental Table corresponding to that which is been available in Tool Master Table

**Rental**

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|tool_no| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|
|  121  | 52 | 89 | 56 | 16 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|
|  142  | 45 | 94 | 89 | 12 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|
|  142  | 24 | 56 | 12 | 89 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|
|  156  | 96 | 89 | 14 | 16 |
|-------|----|----|----|----|
```

**ToolMaster**

```
 _ _ _ _ 
|tool_no|
|-------|
|  121  |
|-------|
|  142  |
|-------|
|  141  |
|-------|
|  150  | 
|-------|
```

my query is given below

```
select tool_no, SUM(a1+a2+a3+a4) AS rentalsum from Rental where tool_no IN(select tool_no from ToolMaster)
```

but i'm not getting the required result

My expected output is like this

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
| tool_no | rentalsum |
|---------|-----------|
|   121   |    213    |
|---------|-----------|
|   142   |    421    |
|---------|-----------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is missing in your current query is the `GROUP BY` clause. [See Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15701/3)

But I rather do it in `JOIN` than `IN`.

```
SELECT  a.Tool_No,
        SUM(b.a1 + b.a2 + b.a3 + b.a4) totalSum
FROM    ToolMaster a
        INNER JOIN Rental b
            ON a.Tool_No = b.Tool_No
GROUP   BY a.Tool_No
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15701/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║ TOOL_NO ║ TOTALSUM ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║     121 ║      213 ║
║     142 ║      421 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tool_no, SUM(a1)+SUM(a2)+SUM(a3)+SUM(a4) AS rentalsum 
from Rental 
Where tool_no in (select tool_no from ToolMaster)
Group By tool_no
```

Using Join

```
  select t.tool_no, SUM(a1)+SUM(a2)+SUM(a3)+SUM(a4) AS rentalsum 
    from Rental t
    Inner Join ToolMaster tm
       ON t.tool_no = tm.tool_no
    Group By t.tool_no
```

Answer (score 0):

USe the following query:

```
SELECT r.tool_no, SUM(r.a1+r.a2+r.a3+r.a4) AS rentalsum 
FROM Rental r INNER JOIN ToolMaster tm 
ON r.tool_no = tm.tool_no
GROUP BY r.tool_no;
```

This will work charm.